# HBase RegionServer abort

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

When I start hbase on my cluster, HMaster process and HQuorumPeer process start on master node while only HQuorumPeer process starts on slaves.

In the GUI console, in the task section, I can see the master (node0) in the state RUNNING and the status "Waiting for region servers count to settle; currently checked in 0, slept for 250920 ms, expecting minimum of 1, maximum of 2147483647, timeout of 4500 ms, interval of 1500 ms". 
In the software attributes section I can find all my nodes in the zookeeper quorum with the description "Addresses of all registered ZK servers".
So It seems that Zookeeper is working but in the log file it seems to be the problem.

Log hbase-clusterhadoop-master:

```
2016-09-08 12:26:14,875 INFO  [main-SendThread(node0:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server node0/192.168.1.113:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (java.lang.SecurityException: Impossibile trovare una configurazione di login) 2016-09-08 12:26:14,882 WARN  [main-SendThread(node0:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)     at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599)   at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)   at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081) 2016-09-08 12:26:14,994 WARN  [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper, quorum=node3:2181,node2:2181,node1:2181,node0:2181, exception=org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
    ........
    2016-09-08 12:32:53,063 INFO  [master:node0:60000] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=node3:2181,node2:2181,node1:2181,node0:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=replicationLogCleaner0x0, quorum=node3:2181,node2:2181,node1:2181,node0:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
    2016-09-08 12:32:53,064 INFO  [master:node0:60000-SendThread(node3:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server node3/192.168.1.112:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (java.lang.SecurityException: Impossibile trovare una configurazione di login)
    2016-09-08 12:32:53,065 INFO  [master:node0:60000-SendThread(node3:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to node3/192.168.1.112:2181, initiating session
    2016-09-08 12:32:53,069 INFO  [master:node0:60000-SendThread(node3:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server node3/192.168.1.112:2181, sessionid = 0x357095a4b940001, negotiated timeout = 90000
    2016-09-08 12:32:53,072 INFO  [master:node0:60000] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Node /hbase/replication/rs already exists and this is not a retry
    2016-09-08 12:32:53,072 DEBUG [master:node0:60000] cleaner.CleanerChore: initialize cleaner=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.master.ReplicationLogCleaner
    2016-09-08 12:32:53,075 DEBUG [master:node0:60000] cleaner.CleanerChore: initialize cleaner=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.snapshot.SnapshotLogCleaner
    2016-09-08 12:32:53,076 DEBUG [master:node0:60000] cleaner.CleanerChore: initialize cleaner=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.cleaner.HFileLinkCleaner
    2016-09-08 12:32:53,077 DEBUG [master:node0:60000] cleaner.CleanerChore: initialize cleaner=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.snapshot.SnapshotHFileCleaner
    2016-09-08 12:32:53,078 DEBUG [master:node0:60000] cleaner.CleanerChore: initialize cleaner=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.cleaner.TimeToLiveHFileCleaner
    2016-09-08 12:32:53,078 INFO  [master:node0:60000] master.ServerManager: Waiting for region servers count to settle; currently checked in 0, slept for 0 ms, expecting minimum of 1, maximum of 2147483647, timeout of 4500 ms, interval of 1500 ms.
    2016-09-08 12:32:54,607 INFO  [master:node0:60000] master.ServerManager: Waiting for region servers count to settle; currently checked in 0, slept for 1529 ms, expecting minimum of 1, maximum of 2147483647, timeout of 4500 ms, interval of 1500 ms.
    2016-09-08 12:32:56,137 INFO  [master:node0:60000] master.ServerManager: Waiting for region servers count to settle; currently checked in 0, slept for 3059 ms, expecting minimum of 1, maximum of 2147483647, timeout of 4500 ms, interval of 1500 ms.
```

Log hbase-clusterhadoop-zookeeper-node0 (master):

```
2016-09-08 12:26:18,315 WARN  [WorkerSender[myid=0]] quorum.QuorumCnxManager: Cannot open channel to 1 at election address node1/192.168.1.156:3888
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:368)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.toSend(QuorumCnxManager.java:341)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.process(FastLeaderElection.java:449)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.run(FastLeaderElection.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Log hbase-clusterhadoop-regionserver-node1 (one of the slave):

```
2016-09-08 12:33:32,690 INFO  [regionserver60020-SendThread(node3:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server node3/192.168.1.112:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (java.lang.SecurityException: Impossibile trovare una configurazione di login)
2016-09-08 12:33:32,691 INFO  [regionserver60020-SendThread(node3:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to node3/192.168.1.112:2181, initiating session
2016-09-08 12:33:32,692 INFO  [regionserver60020-SendThread(node3:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2016-09-08 12:33:32,793 WARN  [regionserver60020] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper, quorum=node3:2181,node2:2181,node1:2181,node0:2181, exception=org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
2016-09-08 12:33:32,794 ERROR [regionserver60020] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 4 attempts
2016-09-08 12:33:32,794 WARN  [regionserver60020] zookeeper.ZKUtil: regionserver:600200x0, quorum=node3:2181,node2:2181,node1:2181,node0:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to set watcher on znode /hbase/master
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.initializeZooKeeper(HRegionServer.java:778)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.preRegistrationInitialization(HRegionServer.java:751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:884)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
2016-09-08 12:33:32,794 ERROR [regionserver60020] zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: regionserver:600200x0, quorum=node3:2181,node2:2181,node1:2181,node0:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.initializeZooKeeper(HRegionServer.java:778)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.preRegistrationInitialization(HRegionServer.java:751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:884)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
2016-09-08 12:33:32,795 FATAL [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: ABORTING region server node1,60020,1473330794709: Unexpected exception during initialization, aborting
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.initializeZooKeeper(HRegionServer.java:778)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.preRegistrationInitialization(HRegionServer.java:751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:884)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
2016-09-08 12:33:32,798 FATAL [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: RegionServer abort: loaded coprocessors are: []
2016-09-08 12:33:32,798 INFO  [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: STOPPED: Unexpected exception during initialization, aborting
2016-09-08 12:33:32,867 INFO  [regionserver60020-SendThread(node0:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server node0/192.168.1.113:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (java.lang.SecurityException: Impossibile trovare una configurazione di login)
```

Log hbase-clusterhadoop-zookeeper-node1:

```
2016-09-08 12:33:32,075 WARN  [QuorumPeer[myid=1]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0:2181] quorum.Learner: Unexpected exception, tries=0, connecting to node3/192.168.1.112:2888
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner.connectToLeader(Learner.java:225)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Follower.followLeader(Follower.java:71)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:786)
2016-09-08 12:33:32,227 INFO  [node1/192.168.1.156:3888] quorum.QuorumCnxManager: Received connection request /192.168.1.113:49844
2016-09-08 12:33:32,233 INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=1]] quorum.FastLeaderElection: Notification: 1 (message format version), 0 (n.leader), 0x10000002d (n.zxid), 0x1 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 0 (n.sid), 0x1 (n.peerEpoch) FOLLOWING (my state)
2016-09-08 12:33:32,239 INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=1]] quorum.FastLeaderElection: Notification: 1 (message format version), 3 (n.leader), 0x10000002d (n.zxid), 0x1 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 0 (n.sid), 0x1 (n.peerEpoch) FOLLOWING (my state)
2016-09-08 12:33:32,725 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /192.168.1.111:49534
2016-09-08 12:33:32,725 WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: ZooKeeperServer not running
2016-09-08 12:33:32,725 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /192.168.1.111:49534 (no session established for client)
```

The conf file abase-site:

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://node0:9000/hbase</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>node0,node1,node2,node3</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/Users/clusterhadoop/usr/local/zookeeper</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/Users/clusterhadoop/usr/local/hbtmp</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.master</name>
        <value>node0:60000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns</name>
        <value>1000</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

Hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       node3
192.168.1.112 node3
192.168.1.156 node1
192.168.1.111 node2
192.168.1.113 node0
```

Any idea on what is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Do you setting every machine hosts file to 127.0.0.1 node3?

Comment: No, I have node0, node1, node2 and node3 according to the considered node.

Comment: Do you zookeeper run ok? you can run zk command to check it.

Comment: What is the command to check zookeeper is working fine?

Comment: Using the command ./hbase zkcli on node0 (master node), after initialization there is: zookeeper.ClientCnxn:Opening socket connection to server node3/192.168.1.112:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL
zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to node3/192.168.1.112:2181, initiating session
[zk: node3:2181,node2:2181,node1:2181,node0:2181(CONNECTING) 0] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server node3/192.168.1.112:2181,sessionid=0x3571d87e5a50002,negotiated timeout=30000
WATCHER::WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null

Comment: Using the ls / command in the Zookeeper shell the result is: [hbase, zookeeper] [zk: node3:2181, node2:2181, node1:2181, node0:2181(CONNECTED) 1]

Comment: please using zookeeper command `bin/zkServer.sh` status on every zookeeper machine. check it's status. and use `bin/zkCli.sh; ls /hbase ` , paste output to us.

Comment: I'm using zookeeper included in hbase. I'm not able to execute the first two commands. Using ls /hbase I obtain: "[backup-masters, table, draining, region-in-transition, table-lock, running, master, hbaseid, online-snapshot, replication, splitWAL, recovering-regions, rs]"

Comment: what's your hbase verion? and why you config four zookeeper nodes? it maybe can not elect a leader node.

Comment: The hbase version is 0.98.11. I follow an example where all nodes have a zookeeper process. Is it wrong?